# scala slick left join multiple tables fetch result as a sequence

Tags: scala, left-join, slick

I'm using scala version 2.12.6 and slick version 3.2.3

I would like to join multiple tables from a postgres database with

- 1:1 relationship between description and product
- 1:0/1 relation
  between product and price and
- 1:n relationship between price and currency

the desired output:

> (description, product, price, Seq[Option[currencies])

what I have so far:

```
 val query = (for {
      (((description, product), price), currencies) <- ((descriptions.filter(_.language === lang.locale.toLanguageTag()) join products on (_.productId === _.id))  joinLeft prices on (_._2.id === _.priceId)) joinLeft currencies on (_._2.map(_.id) === _.priceId)
    } yield (description, product, price, currencies))
```

but this code results in

> (description, product, price, [Option[currencies])

with duplicate rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By SQL-compliant standard, your join/left-join query is rightfully yielding `(description, product, Option[price], Option[currencies])`.

To generate `Seq[Option[currencies]]` instead of Option[currencies], I'm not sure it's doable with Slick.  In theory, a `groupBy` should do, like:

```
val groupQuery = joinQuery.
  groupBy{ case (dsc ,prd, prc, cur) => (dsc ,prd, prc) }.
  map{
    case ((dsc ,prd, prc), group) => (dsc ,prd, prc, group.map(_._2).someAggFunction)
  }
```

Unfortunately, Slick doesn't support groupBy aggregation such as PostgreSQL's `array_agg` or Spark's `collect_list`.  Even if you're by any chance using `slick-pg` on a PostgreSQL database, its [arrayAgg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/agg) method [doesn't work](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/289) as advertised, last I checked.

One workaround as shown in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182305/slick-3-0-many-to-many-query-with-the-join-as-an-iterable) is to use Scala's groupBy on the client side, but it's obviously unscalable.